# plot the iterations of optim vs the logliklihood values in r

Tags: r

I have a function of Maximum likelihood estimation and I am using `optim` function. I would like to plot the iteration outputs vs the logliklihood values.

Here is an very similar example to my complex function:

```
y <- rnorm(1000,2,2)
myfunc <- function(x){
  fn <- function(theta) { sum ( 0.5*(xvec - theta[1])^2/theta[2] + 0.5* log(theta[2]) ) }
  optim(theta <- c(0,5), fn, hessian=TRUE,method = "L-BFGS-B",lower=c(0,0),control = list(trace=1))

}
```

The output is:

```
iter  10 value 12.001318
final  value 12.001318
```

`iter 10` is the iteration step.
`value 12.001318` is the logliklihood value.

my function return `100` of them. I know that I need to store them first and then plot them. But how to do that in R?

any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of options. Option 1: add `REPORT = 1` in the `control` list and the function value will be printed at each step. You would have to process this printed data somehow, maybe by using `sink()` and then removing the extra text. Option 2: run `optim` one iteration at a time and storing values. You can then easily store the log likelihood value and plot it. Partial code for both options is presented below.

```
# generating random values
set.seed(10)
y <- rnorm(1000,2,2)

#### option 1 ####
# intermediate results printed
myfunc <- function(xvec){
  fn <- function(theta) { sum ( 0.5*(xvec - theta[1])^2/theta[2] + 0.5* log(theta[2]) ) }
  optim(theta <- c(0,5), fn, hessian=TRUE,method = "L-BFGS-B",lower=c(0,0),control = list(trace=1,REPORT=1))
}

# running optimization with input y
myfunc(y)

# would need to copy values or otherwise post process to make plot


#### option 2 ####
# running optimization one iteration at a time
fn <- function(theta) { sum ( 0.5*(y - theta[1])^2/theta[2] + 0.5* log(theta[2]) ) }
# storing log likelihood values
loglvals <- fn(c(0,5))

# initializing variables
temp1par <- c(0,0)

# running the loop
for(i in 1:100){

  temp1 <- optim(theta <- ifelse(i==1,1,0)*c(0,5)+ifelse(i==1,0,1)*temp1par, fn, hessian=TRUE,method = "L-BFGS-B",lower=c(0,0),control = list(trace=1,REPORT=1,maxit=1))
  temp1par <- temp1$par
  loglvals <- c(loglvals,temp1$value)
}

# plotting results
# trimming the length of loglvals because the function converged
# before the loop calling optim stopped
# simply using unique to specify when it the optim didn't return new values
plot(seq(0,length(unique(loglvals)),1)
     ,loglvals[seq(1,length(unique(loglvals))+1,1)]
     ,ylab='log likelihood'
     ,xlab='iteration')
```